# Angular ng-repeat exact mach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying out Angular and love it but now I have a small question.

Ok so this is my code:

```
function phonesCtrl($scope) {
$scope.phones = [
    {
        "type":"Smartphone",
    },
    {
        "type":"Smartphone", 
    },
    {
        "type":"Smarterphone", 
    },
    {
        "type":"Smartphones", 
    },
    {
        "type":"Dumbphone", 
    },
    {
        "type":"Dumbphones", 
    }
];
}
  <div ng-controller="phonesCtrl">

    <input type="radio" ng-model="filter.type" value="Smartphone" />Smartphone
    <input type="radio" ng-model="filter.type" value="Dumbphone" />Dumbphone

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="type in phones | filter:filter.type">
        {{phone.type}}
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
```

The code is some what working.. but I want an exact match when selecting a radio... any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`strict`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter) comparator:

```
 <li ng-repeat="type in phones | filter:filter.type:true">
```